# Secure insert queries with go-sql-driver and mysql

Tags: go

I have reviewed the go-sql-driver examples with db.Prepare but I couldn't get it to work properly so I modified it to work directly with db.Query. My understanding is that by using ?? the value is escaped anyway so I was wondering if the following is correct and secure against SQL injection (note that I am using MySQL)

```
stmtIns, err := db.Query("INSERT INTO users (name, address) VALUES(?,?)", name, address) // ? = placeholder
        if err != nil {
            panic(err.Error()) // proper error handling instead of panic in your app
        }
        defer stmtIns.Close() // Close the statement when we leave main() / the program terminates
```

Also, what is the best way to detect if the row has been inserted?

clarification: for secure I meant from SQL Injection. I think it is but then I wonder why all example I could find use db.Prepare and not db.Query as I do.

Comment: Define "secure". Your code is not vulnerable to SQL injection, but is that what you're asking about?

Comment: yes I meant secure from SQL injection. I also want to understand if it is (which I think so) why all examples I could find on go-sql-driver  have db.Prepare and not db-Query

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this safe from SQL injection attacks.

Note that the client code does *not* "escape" parameters in a query of this kind. It does something much simpler and more secure:

The client does not combine `INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES(?)` and the parameter `;DROP TABLE USERS;` into `INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES(;DROP TABLE USERS;`.

Nor does the client do the above with escape characters to make it "safe". The client does *not* construct something like `INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES("\;DROP TABLE USERS\;")`

What it does is send a query to MySQL that contains, separately:

- the query string `INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES(?)` -- MySQL knows this is a query string and knows that the `?` is where parameters are plugged in.
- the parameter `;DROP TABLE USERS;` -- MySQL knows this is a parameter to the query

Hence the *server* knows that the parameter is not SQL code, and that neatly avoids the whole nasty problem of escaping characters.

By choosing not to use `Prepare` you are skipping some potential for optimisation in the server. The server compiles each statement into an internal representation, and this takes time. By making this explicit and re-using the prepared statement, you explicitly save repeating that compilation step.

However, MySQL does cache compiled statements, to avoid repeatedly compiling exactly the same string -- so you probably won't see big performance issues.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Could you please add an example on how it would be done as a prepared statement and perhaps how to check if the query was successful e.g. by printing "record added" ? sorry if this sounds trivial but I think it will benefit other readers too.

Comment: If you want an example of `Prepare` in use, then you should have asked that question. But there are plenty of examples elsewhere, so it's not clear why it belongs in SO. http://go-database-sql.org/prepared.html

Comment: fair enough but my question states Also, what is the best way to detect if the row has been inserted?